# 503 Server Error with new Flexible Environment App

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Created a new Flexible Environment App and made successful deploy with latest GCloud version (current is 133) but get "503 Server Error" without any error logs.

Source code: https://github.com/AIMMOTH/scala-stack-angular/tree/503-error

App link: https://scala-stack-angular-us.appspot.com

```
Error page:
Error: Server Error

The service you requested is not available yet.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Version info:

```
Version Status  Traffic Allocation  Instances   Runtime Environment Size    Deployed    Diagnose

20161108t190158     Serving     100 %    2  custom  Flexible
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue :\

Answer (score 1):

I had a filter responding to /_ah/* and broke Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of wrong settings in `app.yaml`:

```
vm: true                                # the flexible environment
runtime: java                           # Java 8 / Jetty 9.3 Runtime
service: default
threadsafe: true                        # handle multiple requests simultaneously

resources:
  cpu: .5                               # number of cores
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10                      # minimum is 10GB and maximum is 10240GB

health_check:
  enable_health_check: true
  check_interval_sec: 5                 # time interval between checks (in seconds)
  timeout_sec: 4                        # health check timeout interval (in seconds)
  unhealthy_threshold: 2                # an instance is unhealthy after failing this number of consecutive checks
  healthy_threshold: 2                  # an unhealthy instance becomes healthy again after successfully responding to this number of consecutive checks
  restart_threshold: 60                 # the number of consecutive check failures that will trigger a VM restart

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 120             # time interval between auto scaling checks. It must be greater than or equal to 60 seconds.
                                        # The default is 120 seconds
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5             # CPU use is averaged across all running instances and is used to decide when to reduce or
                                        # increase the number of instances (default 0.5)

handlers:
- url: /.*                              # regex
  script: ignored                       # required, but ignored
  secure: always                        # https


beta_settings:
  java_quickstart: true                 # process Servlet 3.1 annotations
  use_endpoints_api_management: true    # enable Google Cloud Endpoints API management
```

I removed `use_endpoints_api_management: true` and everything works fine.